# problem with smbclient login

Tags: smb

I have to copy a file from a linux server to a windows but i have some problems wth the smbclient's login because i need to do this automatically in a script.

This command `smbclient -U LR //10.123.42.144/Doc` ask to type the password so i have found that if you want to skip this you have to use "-U username%password", so i try:

`smbclient -U LR%HH9]\<p# //10.123.42.144/Doc`

but i have this error: failed (Error NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT).

I tried adding -W WORKGROUP but have this another error: session setup failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE

If i type the password manually i can login succefully but how can i do this automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to pass credentials into `smbclient` in a script is probably to use [the `-A` option:](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smbclient.1.html)

> `-A|--authentication-file=filename` This option allows you to specify
>   a file from which to read the username and password used in the
>   connection. The format of the file is
>
> ```
> username = <value>
> password = <value>
> domain   = <value>
> ```
>
> Make certain that the permissions on the file restrict access from unwanted users.

So make a file with your credentials:

**credentials.txt**

```
username=LR
password=HH9]<p#
```

And use that instead of entering your credentials:

```
smbclient -A credentials.txt //10.123.42.144/Doc
```